# "Link" object's text across fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, static

Is there any "trick" in java/android API with `static` or something else to change simultaneously the text in objects with same id across fragments?

Assuming I have a static string:

```
private static String   buttonText = "Today";
```

and each fragment has a button:

```
Button mButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.change_button);
mBotton.setText(buttonText);
```

To change the text on that fragment I do:

```
buttonText = "Tomorrow";
mBotton.setText(buttonText);
```

Can I automatically change the text to the other fragments? Is keeping a `List<Button>` my only way (looping the list and set the text for each of them)?

Comment: Do you know the "Observer Pattern" -> http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer.html

Comment: @Fildor Nope. Looking it now. Is it expensive to use?

Comment: No it's not expensive. The [Observable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html) class gives you most of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is exactly what you need: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

You can build a perfect Oberserver-Like behaviour that fits you needs with this.

1. You create an interface, let's call it `OnButtonTextChangeListener` which defines a method `void onButtonTextChangeWanted( String buttontext )`
2. You have your Activity implement that interface and your Fragments make sure the Activities they are added to do so. (All described in the linked article)
   In that implementation, you change a member of the Activity, which holds the button text, then inform all the registered fragments of the change for example by calling a method `changeButtonText( buttontext )` on the fragments which does what you wrote in your question: change the button on that fragment. That way you distribute the channge to all fragments via the attached activity.

There may be better solutions. My Android is a bit rusty ...

Comment: Your "Observer pattern" solution was fine. I created my own class extending the `Button` class and implementing `Observer`. I added each  button to an `ObservedObject` class which `extends Observable` and has a public method `setValue(String value){setChanged(); notifyObservers(value); }`. When I wanted that value to be changed I called `setValue`. All fragments are always "there" (=created) so I do not have to worry about nullPointers.